# C++ function thinks pointer argument is pointer reference

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

When compiling a library I get the following error related to the function below:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Factor::inplaceCancel(const
>   Factor*&)’

I don't understand why the `const Factor* rhsFPtr` is being treated as a `const Factor*&`.
Could anyone perhaps help me with this?

```
void InplaceCancelFF::inplaceProcess(FactorisedFactor* lhsPtr, const Factor* rhsFPtr){
   lhsPtr->factorPtrs[0]->inplaceCancel(rhsFPtr);
   ...
}
//In the abstract Factor Class:
virtual void inplaceCancel(const Factor* rhsPtr,FactorOperator* procPtr) = 0;
//In the child class:
inline void inplaceCancel(const Factor* rhsPtr, FactorOperator* procPtr = 0);
```

Comment: What overloads of `inplaceCancel` exist?

Comment: Maybe your function declaration doesn't match the definition?

Comment: If the function doesn't exist, your compiler seems to be showing you the most permissive interpretation that *would* be possible: You're making a function call with an lvalue argument, so we *could* bind to an lvalue reference. We could of course also go through lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and bind to a prvalue parameter, but that's just something you can always do with lvalues.

Comment: There are a couple of classes that inherit from the Factor class (which is an abstract class) so the inplaceCancel function for the correct child class should be called. Inside the child class however this function is not overloaded, although it does have an additional optional parameter.

Comment: we need to see the declaration of "inplaceCancel" for more information here.

Comment: The child class signature only matters to the extent that it matches the parent class and overrides it correctly (if C++11, add an `override` directive to the declaration in the child class to ensure this).  The error here is about the parent class.

Comment: declarations added

Comment: Regardless of any other errors, I don't understand why it is saying that the Factor* type argument is of the type Factor*&?

Comment: @ejlouw two possible function signatures (with argument const Factor* and with argument const Factor*&) would satisfy the function call; neither was actually found, so compiler just complain about one of the possible alternatives

Comment: @ejlouw: Your question title suggests that you may not be understanding clearly that *values are never references*. References are only ever the types of variables or formal parameters, never of expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration in the base class has no second default parameter (`procPtr`). So this gets ignored in the child class declarations.

You need to provide 2 arguments to the function for this to work (or at a default to the base declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. There was some function overloading in the base class that I did not see (I'm editing someone else's code). I changed the pointer type to match one of the other functions and that resolved the issue.